# "Invalid_grant" error in IdentityServer4 with authorized_code flow

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I've created a IdentityServer4 project a few days ago using the following template: https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin.
And implemented it in a asp.net core api.
I'm using this api in a Angular project, and i'm using the Authorization_code flow.
I'm succesfully able to use the connect/authorize call using the authorization_code flow with the code_challenge, and i get a code back.
However, when i tried this code with the connect/token call to get an access_token, i get the "invalid_grant" error.

I've already tried tweaking the parameters that i provide with the call,and different ways of passing them.
I also double checked the code_challenge and the sha256 hash of this code_challenge that i provide in the authorize call.
But it seems like as long as i use grant_type=authorization_code i always get the invalid_grant error

The connect/authorize call:

```
https://...com/connect/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&scope=openid profile email roles&response_type=code&code_challenge=(for testing purposes a hash of "test")&code_challenge_method=S256
```

And the connect/token call:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -u "id:secret" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=...&redirect_uri=...&code_verifier=test" https://...com/connect/token
```

The connect/token call always returns `{"error":"invalid_grant"}` as long as i use `grant_type=authorization_code` in the connect/token call.

Comment: You can’t use the connect/token with this grant type as it’s not designed to work without user context.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius How would i continue with this flow then? Because doesn't this already have a user context because i had to login and give consent after i used connect/authorize?

Comment: Are you trying to exchange the code you got back for an access token?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Yes i am

Comment: Ah ok its good then just send all your params to connect/token as post body string and not encoded as form data iirc.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I tried both as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and "application/json", but if i use "application/json" i get a {"error": "invalid_request"} error

Comment: Here is example how to call http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius That's the page i've used to try the call as a normal POST call with the parameters in json format, but unfortunately i still get the invalid_request error when i try that method. I also tried adding the client_secret to the call, but without any succes.

Comment: Check the identity server logs they are usually quite descriptive.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I found the issue. The server says the SHA256 hash it generated of the code_verifier does not equal the one that the client generated and sent during the authorize call. The call works when i use plain instead of S256. What am i doing wrong with hashing that is causing this issue?

Comment: Original authorize request should have `code_challenge` as `Base64Url.Encode.(SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier))`, then the subsequent token request should `code_verifier` as `codeVerifier`. Probably you do something wrong with your original code_challenge parameter.